# Generics - Use return type of a parameter function as return type

Tags: typescript

I have a fancy function that performs a fetch request. The first argument describes the request. The second argument is an optional transformation function:

```js
let data = useData({ /* desc request */}, (res) => res.values)
```

The transform functions transforms the response before the function returns (ie sets `data`).

The signature for these functions are:

```js
// Signature for the transform function
type TransformFn<Data, R> = (data: Data) => R;

// Signature for the fetcher
function useData<Data = any>(
  firstArg: object,
): Data;
function useData<Data = any, R = any>(
  firstArg: object,
  fn?: TransformFn<Data, R>
): R;
```

This works just fine if I do this:

```js
type Response = { values: string[] }

let data = useData<Response, Response["values"]>({ /* desc request */ }, (res) => res.values);
```

*But* it would be amazing if I didn't have to pass in the second type argument (`TransformedData`). I'd love to be able to type the parameter of the transform function, and then let TypeScript's amazing inference take it from there, like this:

```js
let data = useData<Response>({ /* desc request */ }, (res) => res.value);
```

As it stands, `data` just falls back to the default type arg, `any`.

Any hints? Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't it just work if you remove `= any`? You wouldn't even need to explicitly specify the generic type parameters. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgTgQwHYGcBmB7OBbAYkgHgBEFgEAaKAJQD4oBeKACgBNSEAuKEsgSgbpUA3ACgRaAK5IAxsACWGJFAkoIPBMXaVaTEVH1Q0cuCmABBOAHMu68noNokXeMnRY8hW9RojeXKlAA3vb6cBDAEnBKjkxGJuZWvKIAvmKgkNRUEChgiqoMQVAAbggANhLZXKZwckiWANoAulCpIqXhUGxkBSpq7EyBxWUVKFz1AOQI483JlExhKPz0dAsAdCXl2UlAA

Comment: Hey @zerkms - thanks for the response. Issue with the example you gave: The first argument supplied to `useData` is _not_ of type `Data`. The argument is used by `useData` behind the scenes to make a fetch request. _That_ fetch request returns a response (`Data`) that may optionally be passed through the transform function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, TypeScript does not support partial type parameter inference (see [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) for discussion).  Right now it's all or nothing: either you let the compiler infer all of your type parameters, or you specify all of them.  (It might seem like [generic parameter defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) could do this for you since it lets you specify just some of the parameters; but the unspecified parameters are not *inferred*, but take on the *default* value.  Which is not what you want.)

Until and unless microsoft/TypeScript#26242 gets implemented in some way, there are only workarounds.  The two workarounds I usually use are these:

---

CURRYING

Since you can't both specify and infer type parameters on the same generic function, you can split that single generic function into multiple functions, one of which you specify parameters and the other you let the compiler infer them for you.  For example:

```
declare function useDataCurry<D>():
    <R = D>(firstArg: object, fn?: TransformFn<D, R>) => R;
```

Here `useDataCurry()` is a function of no arguments that returns another function.  The `D` (your `Data`) type parameter can be specified on `useDataCurry()`, and the `R` type parameter can be inferred on the returned second function.  You could use it like this:

```
let data0 = useDataCurry<Response>()({ /*desc*/ }); // Response
let data1 = useDataCurry<Response>()({ /*desc*/ }, (res) => res.values); // string[]
```

This is almost exactly what you want, *except* that there's a weird-looking intervening function call.

---

DUMMYING

Another approach is to let the compiler infer all the type parameters, but you pass in a dummy argument of the type corresponding to the ones you'd like to specify.  It doesn't even have to be a real value of the type; you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to make `null` look like the type you want.

For example:

```
declare function useDataDummy<D, R = D>(
    dummyD: D, firstArg: object, fn?: TransformFn<D, R>): R;
```

The `dummyD` argument will be ignored in the implementation of the function, but it lets the compiler know what type you want for `D`:

```
let data2 = useDataDummy(null! as Response, { /*desc*/ }); // Response
let data3 = useDataDummy(null! as Response, { /*desc*/ }, res => res.values); // string[]
```

This is also almost exactly what you want, except that you are specifying the type argument as if it were a regular argument.  Which is weird, but it works.

---

Either way works, but neither way is perfect.  Oh well.  Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBxArtKB1CBBAThAEoQAmEAZgJbA0DmJsA9sFMgN4CwAUD0v0gAuATxjIAKvhCsKTfGABiwADwARADRIiAPiQBeJAApSIQSABcSVQEp9uogG4kPPgPLwANiEJIKaYPCCVCxIaGyqpiBq+kjSwtqGrgIC1PhQggR0lkwARgBWEIHqSUjWlqoOJe5ePn4BQSFhEBFm0QZxmkQxcQklyanpmdn5hYLF3Mn9wAD8lpLSULLySmqd2iVlWpUTAiJiWtAwLGwx7EgAbiAeGFCW6fj0ANoAukgAvi68O-zV3sh1gWCwFC4UiAGE0Ph8MI1Akyn0BMougZVAkBhl8FkkLkCkVfDM5lIZHJFCoNFptLY9PZtiUPBBBEgTGYAAwxJotEAQqEwxhHVgQOGGM4AegAVEzoPAkIQAI43RlikXvaxOEXKvnHCB0hlMyIARnZoLM3OhSMOWqFool5Cg0rlCqQSvemkMhCgVN07oAdJdrtBVUh1Uh7k9np8qoUav9-IDGsaQKo0GAwDDycirL1vpNSMnU6pypp0UNsSM8RQCUh5sTlmS1ptHJ9kvTGcyQAAmI3NSJJlPCQzANAeDwAQliUAOzAFmmttvgzregeDmoFOtbkQAzF3Ob3UwOh6Px5P+WwZ0GxXOF5p3XYZdBfVcbkvlaHgHQXp8Pl8eEA)

Comment: This is such an awesome response, thanks @jcalz. Just experimented, works great. Unfortunately this is for a library so I have a lot of thinking to do.

In any case, how might I improve the title of this question for Google-ability in the future? Wasn't really sure what to call this conundrum.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
function useData<Data = any, R = any>(
  firstArg: object,
  fn?: TransformFn<Data, R>
): R;
```

you could use the [`ReturnType` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypet) with the type of `fn`, which would look this

```
function useData<Data = any>(
  firstArg: object,
  fn?: TransformFn<Data, unknown>
): ReturnType<typeof fn>;
```

This removes the second generic type parameter from your signature, matching what you want from your example, and will type the result of useData to the return type of `fn`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on `ReturnType` - had not heard of that! This gets me closer, but it looks like by marking the second type parameter for `TransformFn` as `unknown`, the return type of `useData` becomes `unknown`. This isn't exactly what I want - I was hoping TS would infer the return type for me

Comment: True. When you actually call useData, the result should have an inferred type of the return type of the function from the second argument, at least. I agree, though, the unknown type isn't very helpful.